# Find exact string and replace or join them

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var theText='Ohhhh #ohhh #oh #ohh #ohhhh ohhh oh'
```

what I want to achieve is for each "oh" with a pound/hashtag would be replaced with a link.

What I want to achieve:

```
"Ohhh <a href='/'>#ohhh</a>
      <a href='/'>#oh</a>
      <a href='/'>#ohh</a>
      <a href='/'>#ohhhh</a>
      ohhh oh
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the snippet below

```
var s = "Ohhhh #ohhh #oh #ohh #ohhhh ohhh oh";
var p = /(#[^\s]+)/g;
s.replace(p, "<a href='/'>$1</a>");
```

Output:

```
"Ohhhh <a href='/'>#ohhh</a> <a href='/'>#oh</a> <a href='/'>#ohh</a> <a href='/'>#ohhhh</a> ohhh oh"
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sQ4fJ5/2)

Answer (score 0):

I got something using `map` native function like bellow.

```
var theText='Ohhhh #ohhh #oh #ohh #ohhhh ohhh oh';
var words = theText.split(' ');
var newWords = words.map(function(part){
        if(part.indexOf('#')==0)
            return "<a href='/'>"+part+"</a>\n";  //\n is because you want line breaks in those words
        else
            return part+" ";
});

var newText = newWords.join('');
console.log(newText);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/88/)

If you want to use it in `HTML` you can use `<br>` at the place of `\n`.

**NOTE:-** `map` doesn't work on IE8 there you have to use some libraries.